# How do I return data from a function in Node that connects to Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function getEmployees(jobID){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("employees").find({employee:jobID}).toArray(function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close();
            console.log(result) // shows the employees. cool!
            // how do I return result??
        })
    })
}
var employees = getEmpoyees(12345);  // I want the employees variable to be an array of employees
```

I'm new to node.js and javascript and I can't figure this out. Do I need to implement a callback to use the data the way I'm trying to?

Comment: Can you share all your code? Have you installed and imported `mongoose` ?

Comment: You won't be able to get the value in that way. Have you used promises before?

Comment: *”Do I need to implement a callback to use the data the way I’m trying to?”* - yes, or better still go learn about Promises (MongoDB uses them out the box). Promises work particularly well with `async` / `await`.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @AlbertoRivera No but I'm researching them now.

Answer (score 4):

Very interesting question.
In this case, you can't return value directly.
So I implemented indirect way to get the return value.
For this, I added "callback" function as the function parameter in "getEmployees" function.
The updated code is as follows.

```
function getEmployees(jobID, callBack){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo.collection("employees").find({employee:jobID}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        db.close();
        console.log(result) // shows the employees. cool!
        // you can return result using callback parameter
        return callBack(result);
    })
})
}
var employees = getEmpoyees(12345, function(result) {
   console.log(result);
});  // I want the employees variable to be an array of employees
```

Comment: *”very interesting question”* - I think you’re confusing “interesting” with “common”.

Comment: this worked! thanks.

Comment: actually, console.log(result) outputs the result but the employees variable is still undefined :(

Comment: The only case the result is undefined is that the function is finished before "return" query. So I think database error is occured before callBack.

Comment: The only case the result is undefined is that the function is finished before 'return' query. I think database error is occurred so callBack didn't run. If my answer is correct, will you vote it?